# typedef unfamiliar syntax (for me)

Tags: c++

Here is a typedef statement from cocos2d-x source:

```
typedef void (Ref::*SEL_CallFunc)();
```

Ref is a class defined somewhere else. I know that this is a typedef for a function pointer but can't get why and how `Ref::` is there. `Ref` class doesn't have a definition for `SEL_CallFunc` anywhere.

How does this work?

Comment: you're looking at a pointer-to-member-function

Comment: It's a typedef for a member function pointer.

Comment: `SEL_CallFunc` is a pointer to a member function of `Ref` that takes no arguments and returns `void`.

Comment: There's so much to learn in C++!